# Error with integration GWT + Hibernate + Postgresql 9.3

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, postgresql-9.3

I have followed this guide

http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html

but I have this errors when I compile under Tomcat:

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/source/../src/ProjectName/src/main/java/../../projectname/client/TestDTO.java'
[ERROR]  No source code is available for type org.hibernate.Session; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR]  No source code is available for type _._.projectname.server.HibernateUtil; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Unable to find type '_._.projectname.client.TestService'
[ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
[ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
[ERROR] Errors in '../../projectname/client/JavaClass.java'
[ERROR] Failed to resolve '_._.projectname.client.TestService' via deferred binding
```

I'm using DTO to mapping bean from server side to client side, JavaClass.java is the class that call the async service, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include server side code in your client package. Any class in your client package would need to be able to be converted to javascript/html. You should make sure all your Hibernate/ domain classes are only referenced in your server package. Also make sure your module.gwt.xml file does not have  entries for your server code path. In this case move your TestDTO to the server package in your project should help.